# Serve two different websites, one under root and another under /news for nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have this set up under Apache but can't get it working under nginx. I have two websites one that covers everything, another under /news/. They run the same framework - Silverstripe.

Here is my nginx conf:

```
server {
      include mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;
      client_max_body_size 0; # Manage this in php.ini
      listen 80;
      listen 443 ssl;
      root /var/www/html/example/webroot;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;

      ssl on;

      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/cert.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/privkey.pem;

      access_log /var/log/nginx/example/access.log main;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/example/error.log;

      # Defend against SS-2015-013 -- http://www.silverstripe.org/software/download/security-releases/ss-2015-013
      if ($http_x_forwarded_host) {
        return 400;
      }

      location ^~ /news/ {
          root /var/www/html/example2/webroot;
          try_files $uri /framework/main.php?url=$uri&$query_string;

          location ~ /framework/.*(main|rpc|tiny_mce_gzip)\.php$ {
          fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
          fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 64k;
          fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
          fastcgi_keep_conn on;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index  index.php;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include        fastcgi_params;
        }

      }

      location / {
        try_files $uri /framework/main.php?url=$uri&$query_string;
      }

      error_page 404 /assets/error-404.html;
      error_page 500 /assets/error-500.html;

      location ^~ /assets/ {
        sendfile on;
        try_files $uri =404;
      }

      location ~ /framework/.*(main|rpc|tiny_mce_gzip)\.php$ {
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
      }

      # Denials
      location ~ /\.. {
        deny all;
      }
      location ~ \.ss$ {
        satisfy any;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
      }
      location ~ \.ya?ml$ {
        deny all;
      }
      location ~* README.*$ {
        deny all;
      }
      location ^~ /vendor/ {
        deny all;
      }
      location ~* /silverstripe-cache/ {
        deny all;
      }
      location ~* composer\.(json|lock)$ {
        deny all;
      }
      location ~* /(cms|framework)/silverstripe_version$ {
        deny all;
      }
}
```

I've tried a few other things similar to this but it always ends up the same result, the server returning a Moved Permanently to the same URL.

Comment: Check your web application. There are no redirects in this nginx configuration.

Comment: The same code works under apache. I can only assume I'm not passing something or the root is not configured correctly under nginx so the application is having issues.

Comment: I see nothing obvious in the nginx configuration. Again, you need to debug your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [walkthrough](https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-php-in-subdirectory) I figured it out:

```
location /news {
  alias /var/www/html/example2/webroot;
  try_files $uri  @news;

  location ~ /framework/.*(main|rpc|tiny_mce_gzip)\.php$ {
       fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
       fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 64k;
       fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
       fastcgi_keep_conn on;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
       include        fastcgi_params;
   }

}

location @news {
   rewrite /news(.*)$ /news/framework/main.php?/$1 last;
}
```